# Proper way to listen for selectionStart and selectionEnd in HTML text inputs to handle leftward dragging of mouse, with knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, textinput, html-input, mouseup

I am listening for `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` with knockout and it's working fine when the user clicks with the mouse and drags *rightward* to create the selection. But if the user clicks in the text and drags the mouse *leftwards* to create the selection, the proper values are not being returned: *selectionEnd and selectionStart are in that case the **same** value, e.g. 6 and 6 when I select a six-letter word moving right-to-left with the mouse.*

Here's my binding:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="textInput: Model.searchWord, event:{keyup: Model.saveSelection, mouseup: Model.saveSelection, mousedown: Model.saveSelection, click: Model.saveSelection}" />
```

P.S. I've also tried without listening for the click event.

and here's the code:

```
    self.selectionStart = ko.observable();
    self.selectionEnd = ko.observable();

self.saveSelection = function (v1, keyEvent) {
        
        self.selectionStart(keyEvent.target.selectionStart);
        if (keyEvent.target.selectionEnd) {
            self.selectionEnd(keyEvent.target.selectionEnd);
        } else {
            self.selectionEnd(0);
        }    

    if (keyEvent.type == "mousedown") return true;
    if (keyEvent.type == "mouseup") return true;            
      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'm working with a home-grown virtual keyboard that injects characters not found on the user's keyboard into the observable backing the Input element. Sometimes it will be an appended or inserted character, and sometimes it will replace a selection. So the selection start and end values have to be captured in the `blur` event as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your JavaScript example:

```
 if (keyEvent.type = "mousedown") return true;
 if (keyEvent.type = "mouseup") return true;
```

You're assigning to keyEvent.type instead of doing a comparison.  Try:

```
 if (keyEvent.type === "mousedown") return true;
 if (keyEvent.type === "mouseup") return true;
```

I have a working example that shows selection correctly at: https://playcode.io/1351651

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out.  Typo crept in here on SO when I was editing the question, not in the original code.

Comment: I needed to get the selectionStart and selectionEnd for the input when I clicked on a virtual keyboard to add a character not available on the physical one; unless I saved those values in the `blur` event, it wasn't working properly at that juncture.